# How to get the current view of the hybrid app to a bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How to get the current view of the app which is hybrid (Native + html) to a bitmap in Android?

This method can only give the native elements:

```
public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
    View screenView = view.getRootView();
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}

// View to BitMap
Bitmap b  = getScreenShot(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```

How can we get the hybrid elements (Native view + HTML content currently being shown)to a bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is sufficient.  The HTML content is in a native view- a WebView.  Pass the WebView into that code and you'll get a Bitmap of the html.  Please note that it will be VERY easy to hit OOM issues here-  HTML content is usually very large in terms of pixels.